# How to import py2neo in Pycharm?

Tags: python, neo4j, pycharm, py2neo

I am a new user of python and the neo4j. I just want to run the python file in Pycharm and connect to Neo4j. But the import of py2neo always does not work, I tried to use Virtualenv but still does not work. I have tried to put my py file inside env folder or outside and both don't work.

I really install the py2neo and the version is the latest,  how to solve this problem​???

My code:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship

graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474")

jack = Node("Perosn", name="Jack")
nicole = Node("Person",name="Nicole")
tina = Node("Person", name="Tina")

graph.create(Relationship(nicole, "KNOWS",jack))
graph.create(Relationship(nicole, "KNOWS",tina))
graph.create(Relationship(tina, "KNOWS",jack))
graph.create(Relationship(jack, "KNOWS",tina))



Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/huangjingzhan/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/neo4j.py", line 1, in <module>
    from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py2neo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check which python version is configured to run the project and make sure that module is installed for that version.

here is how to:
[Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html)

Comment: The problem high probably is that in your OS you have several python installed, and for pycharm  you have chosen a different interpreter

Comment: and new pycharm usually used virtual ENV as default also

Comment: should I put the py file inside the env file or outside? Since I don't know where should I put it....

Comment: no you should not, please follow the instruction in the link in my answer to configure your python interpreter for the project

Comment: OKok I will try again

Comment: This works! I added an interpreter and install py2neo in this interpreter. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install py2neo in virtual environment. if you haven't install. 
and Check you python version on your machine and project.

```
pip install py2neo
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Pycharm Preferences Plugins and look for Graph Database Support and install the plugin, then it should work.